# Error declaration or range of a variable

Tags: vb.net, linq, range, declaration

I am a beginner in vb.net, recently, I have written this query : 
I don't think that explain you the goal of my procedure is important (if it is, do not hesitate to tell me.) 
I have two queries: req1 and req2

```
For i = 0 To My_List.Count - 2

    For j = i + 1 To My_List.Count - 1

        Dim req1 = From Row1 In list_Rows Where Row1.C1.Equals(My_List(i)) Select Row1
        Dim A As Integer = 0

        For Each r In req1

            Dim req2 = From Row2 In list_Rows Where (Row2.C1.Equals(My_List(j)) AndAlso Row2.C2.Equals(Row1.C2)) Select Row2
            A += req2.count

        Next r


    'process....

    Next

Next
```

As you can see in the code below, at the end of req1 I get "Row1". 
I'd like to use Row1 in the second req2 queries. 
But I have the following error message: 
"The name 'Row1' is not declared or is not in the current range."

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is tricky to understand, but I suspect you just need to use `r` (the row in the current iteration) instead of `Row1`. The name `Row1` only has any meaning *within the query expression itself*. So try this:

```
Dim req2 = From Row2 In list_Rows Where (Row2.C1.Equals(My_List(j)) AndAlso 
                                         Row2.C2.Equals(r.C2)) Select Row2
```

(I'm pretty sure there will be more efficient ways of achieving this, admittedly... you should look into joins. However, this will at least get you moving forward a bit.)

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed it works. I'll need some weeks to improve my Linq understanding and then I'll try to use Joins.